# how to upload image to symfony php server

Tags: php, upload, image-uploading, symfony

I have this code that works:

```
session_start();     
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    $params = explode(".", basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    $target = array_values($params)[0];
    $id = array_values($params)[1];
    if ( ($target == "profile") || ($target == "question" && $_SESSION["waitingImagesQuestion"] > 0) || ($target == "answer" && $_SESSION["waitingImagesAnswer"] > 0) ) {
        $imageDirectory = "images/".round(microtime(true)*1000).".png";
        if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $imageDirectory) ) {
            print "success";

        } 
    }
} 
print JsonBuilder::getStringError();
```

Now I want the code that do the same with symfony. 
How can I write it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a cookbook item on Symfony.com explaining how to upload files. Have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html and/or http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html.

To get the Session variable's like the username, you could use the `session` service inside your controller:

```
$this->get('session')->get('username');
```

Comment: I have already read these! I need a code that do the same of mine! because  I have to save the image to my file system and not int DB!

Comment: In the first link there's an example on how to upload a file without storing in the database.

Anyway, if you don't want to use an entity, you can get the file from the request (`$request->files->get('name')`), which is an instance of `UploadedFile`. After that you can just move the file like explained in the documentation (`$file->move($directory, $fileName);`)

Comment: a question, what is name? here  '$request->files->get('name')'

Answer (score 0):

for session you can use $this->getUser()

for upload mabe this link is helpful 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html

Answer (score 0):

this code works!

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class SendImage extends Controller {


    /**
     * @Route("/apprequests/SendImage")
     */
    public function numberAction() {
        $jsonManager = $this->get('epb.JsonManager');
        $session = $this->get('session');
        if ( $session->isStarted() ) {            
            $params = explode(".", basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
            $target = array_values($params)[0];
            $id = array_values($params)[1];
            if ( ($target == "profile") || ($target == "question" && $session->get('waitingImagesQuestion') > 0) || ($target == "answer" && $session->get('waitingImagesAnswer') > 0) ) {
                $imageName = round(microtime(true)*1000).".png";
                $imageDirectory = "images/".$imageName;
                if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $imageDirectory) ) {
                    print "success";
                } 
            }
        } 
        else {
            return new Response($jsonManager->getStringError());
        }
    }
```